# Use Latex in Bokeh axis label

Tags: latex, bokeh

Bokeh does not handle Latex. A solution has been proposed: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/latex.html#userguide-extensions-examples-latex

This is great for adding Latex on top of the canvas. Is there an easy way to use this strategy so we can use Latex in the axis labels?

Answer (score 3):

Bokeh 2.4 adds support for LaTeX (and MathML) to some elements in Bokeh. Currently, you can use LaTeX on axis labels, tick labels, div widgets, and paragraph widgets. LaTeX support for more elements should be added soon. For more information about the new math text feature and how to use them, see the [Bokeh 2.4 release blogpost](https://blog.bokeh.org/bokeh-2-4-6f8a842dfb4f), the new [blackbody radiation example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/latex_blackbody_radiation.html), and the [Bokeh user guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#adding-mathematical-notations)!

[image]

Comment: Any update on this now that bokeh v2 has been released?

Comment: Initial support added in 2.4, update above.